# Name workspaces in Ubuntu 18

Tags: workspaces

When I click the windows key, on the right, I can see [my workspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sEOvi.jpg). Thing is, I can't seem to name them like in Windows. Is it possible to easily name & view workspaces, so that when I go to the workspaces, I can see the name I gave to each one?

I'm on ubuntu 18.04.

Huge thanks ahead!

Comment: If you use Compiz as your window manager (it's non-default, so if you are using it you probably know it :)), there is an option "Workspace Naming" in CompizConfig. I don't know for the default WM (Metacity).

Comment: Ubuntu has two different products, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS is a *deb* based system using the *year.month* format, and Ubuntu 18 in your heading is closest to Ubuntu Core 18 which is a *snap* only system.  Please clarify as you imply a *snap* only product, but that differs to the 18.04 you mention and picture of desktop you describe & provide.  Ubuntu releases using *year* only are different products to the *year.month* systems.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've enabled `workspace naming` from it. I have two questions if that's okay. 1 - where do i see the actual text? I'm asking because it says "Centered on screen" but i don't see it anywhere. 2 - is it possible to edit the names from the workspace preview itself? Would be kind of annoying to change it form `CompizConfig` everytime. Thanks ahead!

Comment: As there is a "Display Time" option in the same place where is "Centered on screen", I guess the text is displayed for the specified time after you switch to that workspace.

Comment: I also suggest that you enable "Desktop Wall" in CompizConfig if you don't have it already, then you will see a preview of all your workspaces when switching with Ctrl-Alt-Left/Ctrl-Alt-Right.